# Getting Facebook Profile in another activity after logging in

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

Hey everyone i found on youtube interesting tut for Facebook implementation although there methods are deprecated but i found it easy to work with since i am new to Facebook implementation in my android application. I am facing some issue, i am logging in successfully into Facebook with the login activity but in there tut they show the user profile in same activity, in my case i don't want that i wanna show them in another activity i saved the user credentials in shared preference and the session is valid but while implementing the parse stuff of the user profile i am getting nothing don't know why here is my code.

enter code here

```
private void updateView() 
{
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    if(fb.isSessionValid())
    {
        Intent openActivity=new Intent(FacebookLoginActivity.this,AccountInfoActivity.class);
        startActivity(openActivity);
    }
}
```

here the session in valid so i am able to go to the next activity

enter code here

```
 public class AccountInfoActivity extends Activity
{
Facebook fb;
String id,name,email;
Bitmap bmp;
ImageView profile_pic;
TextView facebook_name,facebook_email;
@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_account_profile);

    String APP_ID= "**************";
    fb= new Facebook(APP_ID);

    profile_pic=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.profile_pic);
    facebook_name=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.facebookName);
    facebook_email=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.facebookEmail);

     (new DataProgressTask()).execute();

}
 public class DataProgressTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Boolean> 
{
    ProgressDialog progress;

    public DataProgressTask() 
    {
        progress = new ProgressDialog(AccountInfoActivity.this);
    }
    protected void onPreExecute() 
    {
            progress.setMessage("Loading data ...");
            progress.show();
    }
    @Override
    protected void onCancelled() 
   {
        if ( progress != null )
        {
            progress.dismiss();
        }
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(final Boolean success) 
    {
        //Check if dialog still runing dismiss  
        if ( progress != null)
        {
            progress.dismiss();  
        }

        if (success)
        {
            facebook_name.setText(name);
            facebook_email.setText(email);
            profile_pic.setImageBitmap(bmp);
        }
        else
        {
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Check your Internet Connection", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }


    }
    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    protected Boolean doInBackground(final String... args) 
    {
        if(fb.isSessionValid())
        {

            JSONObject obj= null;
            URL img_url = null;

            String jsonUser;

            try 
            {


                jsonUser = fb.request("me");
                obj = Util.parseJson(jsonUser);

                id = obj.optString("id");
                name= obj.optString("name");
                email= obj.optString("email");
                //getting the image of the user
                img_url = new URL("http://graph.facebook.com/"+id+"/picture?type=small");
                //decode it to bitmap
                bmp =BitmapFactory.decodeStream(img_url.openConnection().getInputStream());
                profile_pic.setImageBitmap(bmp);

            } 
            catch (MalformedURLException e)
            {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } 
            catch (IOException e) 
            {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } 
            catch (FacebookError e) 
            {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } 
            catch (JSONException e) 
            {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        return true;
    }

   }}
```

Any help would be appreciated.
Thank you

Answer (score 1):

I manage to solve my issue by sending the data of the profile of the user through intent from the login activity to the other activity all that done if the session is valid :D